# Change combobox selected item with button vb.net

Tags: vb.net, combobox, selecteditem

I wanted to know if it is possible to have two buttons that change the currently selected item of a combobox "up one" or "down one".
So I would have two buttons: next and back, and when you click on next, the selected item in the combobox will change to the one lower in the list (1 -> 2), and if you click back, it will return to the previous item (1 <- 2).
Thanks in advance,

Comment: yes it is possible. just change the currently selected item up or down as needed

Comment: Yes but how would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Something like...

```
Private Sub btnUp_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnUp.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex - 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnDown_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnDown.Click
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex < ComboBox1.Items.Count - 1 Then
        ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = ComboBox1.SelectedIndex + 1
    End If
End Sub
```